# Print a numerical triangle

Tags: python

You are given a positive integer (example: N = 6). Print a numerical triangle of height  like the one below:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Use no more than two lines of code.
Use a for loop and print function only.
You can't use anything related to strings.
N is an input.

What I tried:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print(*range(1, i+1))
```

my output:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: This isn't your fault, but "Do it in only two lines of code" is a terrible school assignment. That's called code golf, and it's *not* a good way to learn a language. Whoever gave you this assignment is incredibly misguided.

Comment: Hint: `string * i` concatenates `i` copies of `string`.

Comment: Can use `join` or not. its a method.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get the triangle indicated (without using strings) is to treat the output as numbers and to calculate those numbers:

```py
N = 6
for i in range(1, N):
    print(sum(10**j for j in range(i)) * i)
```

Output as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list multiplication, list unpacking and `print`'s capability of taking multiple arguments and outputting them separated by `sep` to produce the correct output:

```py
for i in range(1, int(input())):
    l = [i] * i
    print(*l, sep="")
```

Or on two lines:

```py
for i in range(1, int(input())):
    print(*[i] * i, sep="")
```

Comment: "invalid string literal found" this is what I'm told

Comment: @purplegeminii you have to enter a valid integer …

Comment: The code test is automatic and they use n = 5, to test

Comment: @purplegeminii I do not know why that's happening, but the code is running fine when pasted into the Python console and executed …

Answer (score 1):

Tell whoever left this assignment you did it in one line and no strings used:

*be careful what you wish for*

```
_ = [print((10**i  - 1)//9 * i) for i in range(1, 6)]
```

if you hate math:

```
_ = [[print(i, end='' if j != i-1 else '\n') for j in range(i)] for i in range(1, 6)]
```

Personally I prefer this one for this assignment:

```
_ = [print(i*int(bin((1 << i) - 1)[2:])) for i in range(1, 6)]
```

Comment: If you're going to use list comp, the value should be assigned to remove the implicit return printout.  For example `_ = [...]`.  And let's be honest ... these statements (while fun, sure) aren't very Pythonic given their unnecessary compeixity.

Comment: my point is the question formulation itself is not friendly for beginners at all ... it is as if the person has one particular solution in mind and is forcing the students to come up with it

Comment: Absolutely agreed. A fun challenge - but certainly not the way to teach, *especially* beginners.

Comment: yes - so if he/she wants it to be complicated let's make it unnecessarily complicated XD

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

edit: Now without using string function.

```py
n = 6 # write you value here.
for a in range(1,n):
    print(f'{a}'*a)
```

Comment: You did their home work for them.

Comment: In fairness, they DID make a good faith effort, and just had a bug.  In my mind, this kind of help is OK.

Comment: @TimRoberts I do not answer if the guy has not tried but he tried and get some bug.

Comment: "invalid string literal found" this is what I'm told

Comment: I would suggest that `f'...'` *is* using something related to strings.

Comment: @quamrana if you think `f'...'` is for the string then print could be a function for string.

Comment: Well, possibly, except `print()` seems to be explicitly allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print(str(i)*i)
```

Comment: @SharimIqbal and D.Manasreh: It looks like none of you read the question properly … __`You can't use anything related to strings`___

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be

```
for i in range(1, int(input())+1):
    print(*[i for j in range(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one function that works.

def f(n):
a=''
for i in range(1,n):
a=a+'1'
print(i*int(a))